# Multiform DataGridView and DetailView Issues

Tags: c#, datagridview, detailsview

I am trying to make a multiform application that takes a DataGridView of table attributes and shows them in a DetailView upon the click of a button. When I click the button and the second form opens it is empty. Then if I close the second form I get 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred'. Here is my code:

Form 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultiForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form2
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'personnelDataSet.employee' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.personnelDataSet.employee);

        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 dForm = new Form2();
            dForm.ShowDialog();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.personnelDataSet);
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultiForm
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        //public Form2()
        //{
        //    InitializeComponent();
        //}

        private void employeeBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.employeeBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.personnelDataSet);

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'personnelDataSet.employee' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.personnelDataSet.employee);

        }
    }
}
```

I get the exception on form 1 at `this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.personnelDataSet);` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't drag in the data components into the tray duh... Sorry guys.